# How can I reduce spacing between items in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have a simple question , I have a RecyclerView with 10 items, an Horizontal Scroll with paging Activated and my items appears in the middle like this :

[image]

What do I want now it's to have this. As you can see the next item is visible on the screen :

[image]

Here is my xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/square"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/square_elem"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My MainActivity :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
{
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    recyclerInit()

    }

fun recyclerInit()
{
     val list : ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()


    for (i in 1..10) {
        list.add("$i")
    }

    recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, 
    LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)


    recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true)

    recyclerview.adapter = RecyclerAdapter(list)

    val snapHelper = PagerSnapHelper()
    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerview)
    }
}
```

And This is my Adapter :

```
class RecyclerAdapter(val list: ArrayList<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>()
{

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate((R.layout.box_elem), parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return position.toLong()
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return position
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return list.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.original_box)
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        removeElemAt(position);
    })
}

fun removeElemAt(position: Int) {
    list.removeAt(position)
    notifyItemRemoved(position)
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, list.size)
}

class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    var image: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.box_elem)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your image view has constraint to your parent, remove it or try to set your constraint layout width to wrap content

Comment: make height and width wrap_content of your root layout.

Comment: If I remove constraint my item will not be in the middle of the screen.

Comment: use viewpager instead with 10 different fragments added to it.. I can tell you how to do it

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to use viewpager , i really want to stay like this

Comment: @primo your solution is bit costly for the task. And for the solution, you can either use wrap content to the parent as others suggested. or you can remove the parent itself. That is, use ImageView directly without any parent.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

RecyclerView xml:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

YourItem xml:

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="YourOption"
    android:layout_height="YourOption">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="YourOption"
                android:layout_height="YourOption"
                android:gravity="YourOption"
                android:scaleType="YourOption"
                />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

change your layout with this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/square"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/square_elem"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I have now two items on screen but the first one is not center in the middle of the screen , and my paging doesn't work properly now

Comment: fix image height and width

Comment: My Image height and width are wrapping my content as you can see , what do you mean about "fix"

Comment: android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"

Comment: Doesn't work , I really need to keep the size of the content but just put it in the middle of the screen like you can see on the first screenshot, but with the next item visible next to him

Comment: use relativelayout/linerlayout insted of ConstraintLayout